# Package to create a printable form

Tags: packages

I need to create a printable form. Please suggest a LaTeX package that can do these types of questions:

- Text:

```
1. Your e-mail: __________________________
```

- Paragraph:

```
2. Describe your neighborhood:

_____________________________
_____________________________
_____________________________
```

- Choose one:

```
3. Your one most favorite fruit:

() Apple   () Pear
() Orange  () Other: ___________
```

- Choose many:

```
4. Pick two fruits that you love least of all:

[] Apple  [] Pear
[] Orange [] Other: ___________
```

- Grid:

```
5. Rate your attitude to these fruits:

        Hate   Don't like  Indifferent   Like   Love
Apple    ()         ()         ()         ()     ()
Orange   ()         ()         ()         ()     ()
Pear     ()         ()         ()         ()     ()
```

*Update:* I've edited the question to remove misleading word "questionnaire". I need forms, to get statistics from, not exams and quizzes. Sorry, I'm a bit lost at the English terminology on the subject. See above examples to better understand what I need.

Comment: that are always simple tabulars ...

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one looks really close to what I need:

http://www.qdds.org/fileadmin/files/Documentation_en_papi.pdf

Only I can't figure out where to download it. :-(

Comment: I tried and can't find it as well. All my Google-Fu didn't helped. Seems to be a student project that was never really published.

Comment: Looks like it lives here: http://www.qdds.org/fileadmin/files/latexstyles.zip

Comment: Ahh, hiding behind ZIP Files! Ts, ts :-) Just out of interest: how did you find it finally?

Comment: Well, just opened the directory listing for http://qdds.org/fileadmin/files/

Comment: Implementation seems to be a bit too much ad-hoc though... Had to hack it in several places.

Answer (score 6):

Recommendable packages are

- [`exams`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) - a feature-rich package for creating questions
- [`qcm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/qcm) - for making multiple choices questionnaires

More can be found in the section [Typesetting Exam Scripts, Quizzes, Flashcards, and Questionnaires](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#exams) in the TeX Catalogue.

Comment: Um. Sorry, but in the documentation for both packages I fail to find relevant examples. Most important for me is the support for the Grid type of question.

Comment: Also, please note that I'm not creating quiz or exam form. I've updated the question to clarify this. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

For creating questionnaires with LaTeX I can recommend:

http://www.svenhartenstein.de/creating-questionnaires-with-latex/

Comment: The demo for this package does not have Grid questions... Are they supported?

Comment: Can be easily done using a `tabular` where the tick cells contain `\QO`.