# Creating fillable PDFs

Tags: pdf, forms

I'd like to create a LaTeX document that when rendered into PDF, has forms that can be filled out using Adobe Reader or other such programs. Then I'd like to be able to extract the data. I deliberately would like to avoid using Acrobat for all the usual reasons (non-free, need different versions for different platforms etc).

Can this be done ?

Comment: Creating a PDF form using pdflatex should be possible. However the "Then I'd like to be able to extract the data" part is then only a PDF issue. IIRC the PDF can be transmit the form to a web server. How exactly do you want to extract the data?

Comment: @Suresh Try this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7869/how-do-you-say-happy-new-year-with-latex, if this is what you are looking post a comment and I will add some explanations. Also search the JavaScript tag.

Comment: @Yiannis: that's an interesting trick. Makes me think though that I should give up on the latex and just use HTML + javascript. @Martin, even extracting to a text file would be fine.

Comment: @Suresh Best option would be in this case -- and I hate to say so to actually buy Acrobat Professional. It can do all these much easier transmit to the web collate the data etc...

Comment: @Yiannis that just makes me sad :)

Comment: It would help some one can help for this
http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28830/5149

Comment: @Brendan It's not the easiest thing to transfer from one type of program to the other. Also, I highly doubt that HTML websites are printable.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The `hyperref` package provides a method to create PDF forms. The way I understand it, the form is either to be printed or to be transmitted to a webserver like a HTML form.

Here a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}[action={http://your-web-server.com/path/receiveform.cgi}]
\begin{tabular}{l}
    \TextField{Name} \\\\
    \CheckBox[width=1em]{Check} \\\\
    \Submit{Submit}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}


\end{document}
```

#### Gives:

[image: Result]

Comment: while both answers are great, this one is closer to what I need because it allows extraction of the data via a CGI script.

Comment: @Suresh: Give it a few hours (to see if there is another solution), then accept this one if it's still the best approach for you.

Comment: yes, I was planning to wait a bit. I just wanted to clarify the things that were more important (extraction being one)

Comment: I've just created an example: http://martin-thoma.com/creating-pdf-forms-with-latex/

Comment: Does this work for local files? I.E. can I set the action of this to a local $.cgi$ file?

Comment: See [here](https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-200006) for available fields and optional parameters (e.g. `borderwidth=0` to remove red boxes).

Comment: We can found a tutorial (english and german) at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/pdf-forms-tutorial

Comment: Is there an easy way to make a field where users can fill out a date?  i.e., I want something with 3 fillable entries that looks like __/__/____

Comment: This works, but I would recommend a file upload instead currently: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366238/19083

Comment: Does this work for printing? AFAICT the forms end up as part of the annotation layer, not the content layer. I can only seem to print content, rather than annotations. I'd really like a solution that works for both print and digital.

Answer (score 56):

Here is some code that I use to create forms that can be either printed and filled out with a pen or filled out electronically in a PDF viewer. When printed, the form provides a line for each form field. Like Martin Scharrer's solution I'm using the `hyperref` package. The tricky bit was to define an input field of a given length (here `textwidth` minus 4 cm). It required to override the `\LayoutTextField` hook.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\newdimen\longline
\longline=\textwidth\advance\longline-4cm

\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2} % override default in hyperref

\def\lbl#1{\hbox to 4cm{#1\dotfill\strut}}%
\def\labelline#1#2{\lbl{#1}\vbox{\hbox{\TextField[name=#1,width=#2]{\null}}\kern2pt\hrule}}

\def\q#1{\hbox to \hsize{\labelline{#1}{\longline}}\vskip1.4ex}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Form}
    \q{First Name}
    \q{Last Name}
    \q{Email}
   \end{Form}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

In a PDF viewer each line becomes a form field.

Comment: To turn off red boxes: `\def\labelline#1#2{\lbl{#1}\vbox{\hbox{\TextField[name=#1,width=#2,borderwidth=0]{\null}}\kern0pt\hrule}}`.

Comment: This command from @Adobe comment does not work for me. It compiles only if i exclude `borderwidth=0`. Any other tips on "turnning of red boxes"?

Comment: @DrBeco : For some reason copypasting Adobe's line doesn't seem to work indeed.  Just add `,borderwidth=‌​0` in Christian's original code.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou Doing `\def\labelline#1#2{\lbl{#1}\vbox{\hbox{\TextField[name=#1,width=#2,borderwidth=‌​0]{\null}}\kern2pt\hrule}}` gives many warnings but almost completely removes the red surrounding boxes. What do you think?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Well, I think this looks exactly like what I was suggesting… :P  The difference with Adobe's comment being the value after `\kern`.  Your last comment probably deserves a question of its own.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou Expanded here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386576/13173 for many lines on `\q{}`.

Comment: Note on this answer, `name` cannot include a period https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641508/begin-end-form-makes-textfield-inputs-unfillable

Comment: Why not `\TextField[bordercolor=0 0 0,borderstyle=U,width=.9\textwidth]{Name}
` ? to remove the box, change the color and expand the field to 90% of textwidth ?

Answer (score 38):

I've used the [`eforms`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eforms) package, which is used by [DANTE](http://www.dante.de/) for their [membership form](http://www.dante.de/index/Intern/Mitglied/AntragStandardSepa.pdf) (which of course I can't now locate in `.tex` format!). You'll probably have to download and unpack `eforms` from CTAN yourself, as it's not in TeX Live (unpack `eforms`, `insdljs` and `taborder`, all in the `eforms` bundle). A short example from a registration form I've done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}

% From DANTE's registration form!

\newcounter{infoLineNum}
\setcounter{infoLineNum}{0}
\newcommand{\infoInput}[2][4in]{%
  \stepcounter{infoLineNum}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \kern 4 pt
    \raisebox{.75ex}
      {\textField[\W0\BC{}\BG{}\TU{#2}]{name\theinfoLineNum}{#1}{12bp}}%
  }
    \dotfill
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lp{4in}}
   Title                 & \infoInput{Title}\\[6pt]
   First name            & \infoInput{Firstname}\\[6pt]
   Last name             & \infoInput{Surname}\\[6pt]
   E-mail address        & \infoInput{Email}\\[6pt]
   Dietary requirements  & \infoInput{Dietary}\\[6pt]
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Student (\pounds60) 
    & \raisebox{.75ex}{\radioButton{RegType}{10bp}{10bp}{Student}} 
      \\[6pt]
  Academic/post-doc (\pounds120)
    & \raisebox{.75ex}{\radioButton{RegType}{10bp}{10bp}{Academic}} 
      \\[6pt]
  Industrial (\pounds180)
    & \raisebox{.75ex}{\radioButton{RegType}{10bp}{10bp}{Industrial}} 
      \\[6pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This gives 'type in' boxes for the text areas and 'tick' boxes for the choices.

I'm not sure what happens about saving form data: according to Adobe Reader it can't be saved in this form. I've never actually seen a PDF form that can have the data saved, so whether even Acrobat can do this I do not know.

Comment: @Joseph Wright you need Acrobat professional to save the data, if I recall correctly, if you have it you can also enable the final copy of the pdf to be saved by those using the Reader alone.

Comment: Or, if you use a Mac, Preview allows you to save the data.

Comment: @Alan: I tried that, but it did not seem to work

Comment: @Joseph I haven't tried the `eforms` package itself, but I routinely generate a syllabus for a course I supervise using `hyperref`'s pdf forms methods, and if you fill in the form and then Save As in Preview, it saves the filled in form.

Comment: It is possible to save the data with Reader for some forms. An example is the US Tax form at http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf

Comment: @Boris: I guess they've _made_ the form with Acrobat Pro. That can enable features in Reader with suitably-prepared PDF files.

Comment: I've found that [PDF-Xchange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) (it's free) on Windows and the evince Document Viewer on Linux can save the data with PDF forms.

Comment: @Joseph: In case you're still interested in retrieving the membership form in `.tex` format, it is actually attached to the [application form](http://www.dante.de/index/Intern/Mitglied/AntragStandard.pdf) itself. Like a first goodie for new members :)

Comment: Okular can also now save the filled out form with the data in the PDF itself, provided it is compiled with a recent version of poppler (which is probably what evince uses, as well).

Comment: Output: `! LaTeX Error: File 'eforms.sty' not found.` in TeXLive 2017. How do you get the package there?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영you download from CTAN and compile the files that are needed from the ins Format, e.g.: `pdflatex eforms.ins` for the package and `pdflatex eforms.dtx` for the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

**`action=` submission dangers**

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14844/19083 works, but the proposed method is:

- dangerous:

  - user may submit form twice and not notice it
  - no authentication, so a malicious user could submit it multiple times
- not portable: Evince 3.24.0 (default reader Ubuntu 17.04) doesn't implement HTTP submission (tested with `nc localhost 8000`).

I would recommend instead that you remove the `action` and submit button as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    \TextField{Name} \\
    \CheckBox[width=1em]{Check} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

and use a programmatic method to extract the PDF data as mentioned at:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984003/how-to-extract-pdf-fields-from-a-filled-out-form-in-python
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009608/how-to-export-pdf-form-fields-to-xml-automatically

and then ask users to upload the PDF if you are using a web server.

I have tested Python's `pdfminer`, and it just worked, outputting:

```
Name: asdf
Check: /Yes
```

Note that you have to save a new PDF first after modifying the fields with Evince.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with [Christian Lindig's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14845/45252). It looks good.

The problem is that there are red border around the fields.  Guys in this community do gave some suggestions on how to remove that.  To me, the simplest one is

```
\def\labelline#1#2{\lbl{#1}\vbox{\hbox{\TextField[name=#1,width=#2,bordercolor=white]{\null}}\kern2pt\hrule}}
```

Just change the color of the border.  Remember to include the `xcolor` package.

Maybe I should write this in the comments, but I am new here.

Comment: Confirm! This works best. `borderwidth=0` like proposed before gives many warnings and is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

We can search it at CTAN like this: https://www.ctan.org/topic/form-fillin

- `for­mu­lar` (it will create fields to be filled by hand or computer. I did not like because it doesn't have checkbox) [check the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/formular/formular.pdf)
- `hyperref` - [manual](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf#section.6)

The others results were not nice.

I will try `hyperref` later.

Comment: This is more commentary as you only mention some packages explaining the how and hyperref is already covered by another answer.