# Typeset content of a PDF text-field without recompilation

Tags: pdf, printing, forms

With respect to preparing a PDF for printing:

Is it possible to provide a *text-field* in PDF where I can type something and it should be typeset for printing?

A *resume* for example :

Most of the content in my resume remain same, only few fields require changes,
so I was thinking of providing text-fields where I can enter changes and get typeset printouts, without much worrying about compiling it again.

This is for portability, most of the printing shops would not have TeX installed on their computers. This will come in handy.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to print the content of a text-field in PDF but you can't really typeset it like the rest of document. This means you don't get the same typographical quality for this parts, e.g. no hyphenation etc. I'm not sure if it is even the same font. Also normally you can't save any changes to the PDF form if you don't have the right software like the expensive Adobe Acrobat full version.

It is not really possible to call (La)TeX from inside a PDF document and make a new PDF. At least it wouldn't be any easier than to simply edit the text in the source file. You could define your own class or template to simplify the required changes. For example you could define the complete style and have some own macros and/or environments to easily input the required information. This of course represents an initial overhead of work.