# Creating a form action which generates a PDF

Tags: pdf, forms

This is not a duplicate question!

The thread I have been referred to uses highly OS dependent ways of accomplishing this task. I am looking for something that OS independent.

Please remove the duplicate classification.

---

I am trying to create some forms using `hyperref`. Looking at [documentation from Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WSBB6EF75F-BC3D-4094-B787-FB76DAE1EBDC.w.html), it appears that it is possible to simply generate a PDF (that a user could save to a PDF file) with user input. Using the following code construct:

```
\begin{Form}{action=XXX}
...
\end{Form}
```

what should XXX precisely be for my case? I could not find any relevant Adobe or `hyperref` documentation. There are examples of XXX for mailing the form, or sending off the data to a cgi script, but not what I am looking for.

Comment: Not really. The solutions in that thread are highly OS dependent and do not answer my question (XXX?).

Comment: i doubt you can do any better than to write a cgi script that compiles to pdf.  which will of course be os dependent.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no better answer to your question than what is already provided in [Save fillable forms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29842/3323): If you want users to be able to save a PDF form directly, they a) have to use Adobe Reader XI (available for Windows and Mac), or b) you have to acquire Adobe Acrobat Professional to specially "treat" your PDF form so that users can save it with older versions of Adobe Reader (e.g. version 9, which is the latest version for Linux), or c) they have to use another viewer altogether, which supports saving filled forms (OS dependent, of course).

Comment: @user2751530: I agree with diabonas, because I have done some research concerning this topic. Without Acrobat Prof. edition it is not possible to enable the Reader treating form fields editable. The most you can reach is to make user input to be printed in to flat `.pdf` file, i.e. the input is hardwired into `.pdf` background, visible, but not editable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess this is a dark side of using PDFs. How do I make user input into a flat .pdf file? That would suffice for our purposes as there is no reason for the user to re-edit previously edited information.

Comment: Choose print into a file.

Comment: I've closed (again) here as _there is no 'better' way_. Solutions that exist are OS-dependent as the PDF spec itself does not offer what is wanted.