# Creating a PDF form that accepts uploaded images

Tags: graphics, pdf, forms

I am creating some forms that require users to stick photos in boxes. I was wondering if one could, with some PDF magic, create forms that could accept user supplied (via an upload button on the form) digital images (and size them using `\includegraphics`), and then generate a user saveable PDF.

I have found [almost nothing](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/844010) so far on doing this.

Comment: As always with solutions to PDF forms etc: It requires often a setup specific to a PDF viewer, most probably Adobe Reader. And: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What do you suggest would be an MWE for a feature that I know nothing about?

Comment: Probably yes, but it will need JavaScript support. For generating PDF, see the comments on [Creating a form action which generates a PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174620)

Comment: Thanks for directing me to another of my own threads :) That thread has nothing to do with images. Could you suggest a simple example that could do something like this (even if it means creating a flat PDF at the end of the day)?

Comment: You mention using `graphicx` so is the idea that the form would submit the images, together with other data, to your server which would then run pdfLaTeX (or whatever) to produce a PDF for return to the user? If so, might it be easier to produce the initial form as a web page (with javascript or whatever) rather than as a PDF? There doesn't seem to be  any need to use PDF for the input, and it just introduces complexities which are likely to cause incompatibilities with PDF viewers of various kinds. That is: why does the input need to be PDF as well as the output?

Comment: It needs to be a PDF because these are standalone forms for use by people who are not LaTeX literate.

Comment: @user2751530 I don't see why that means it needs to be PDF. If the idea is for your server to generate the PDF from a template + their inputted/uploaded data/images, you just need an interface to let them do the inputting/uploading. That could be a web page. Your server then generates the PDF. The user doesn't need to even know LaTeX is involved. That stuff is all just server stuff on your side. Note that you can't, as it were, use `graphicx` ***within*** a PDF. You can only use it in a `.tex` file which you'll compile to produce a PDF. Hence my puzzlement.

Comment: Usually PDF forms, like HTML(Website) forms, submit their content to a server. If it is possible to add images this way, you still need a webserver with LaTeX installed, which receives the content, adds it to a LaTeX template, compiles it and provides the final PDF to the user. This way a browser is needed anyway, so I don't see the benefit of a PDF form against an HTML form.

Comment: Approaches regarding how to upload images to a PDF form are being discussed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/656276/47927