# Latex fillable PDF image field

Tags: hyperref, forms

I want to create a pdf in which the user can insert an image. I thought that might be easiest with an image field but i didn’t find anything.

---

Thank you, @UlrikeFischer! Is there a way to combine this with my already existing hyperref form? I read in the documentation, that it is possible, but the way suggested doesnt work.
Here an example I wrote:

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}
\begin{document}
    \Form

    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \group_begin:
    \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_tl{event.target.buttonImportIcon();}
    \pdf_object_unnamed_write:nx{stream}{{}{\exp_not:o{\l_tmpa_tl}}}
    \pdfannot_dict_put:nnx{widget}{A}{<</S/JavaScript /JS~\pdf_object_ref_last:>>}
    \pdffield_pushbutton:n{name=bild,width=10cm,height=8cm,MK/TP=1}
    \group_end:
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    
        \begin{Form}
                    
            \TextField[name = namename1,
            bordercolor={},
            height=45pt,
            width=\textwidth,
            color=black,
            align=1,
            charsize = 45pt]
            {}
        \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

It throws this error:

```
LaTeX3 Error: The key property '.legacy_if_set:n' is unknown. }
```

Also I tried to print the PDF with an image, but it it is blank.

Thanks again for any answer!

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean, but perhaps https://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/10834/formulaire-pdf-avec-image-modifiable

Comment: Do you want include a graphic?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the following is possible (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64467738/9303652)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\PushButton[
    name=namename1,
    bordercolor={},
    align=1,
    onclick={
        event.target.buttonPosition = 1;
        event.target.buttonImportIcon();
    }
]{\parbox[t][40pt]{0.5\textwidth}{\hfill}}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

It seems that you need to place something into the label of the `\PushButton` in order to make it visible. Also, the `width` and `height` options seem to have no effect. Therefore, I used a reasonably sized `\parbox` and filled it with some invisible space.