# Enable Adobe extended pdf features in latex, backwards compatibility for saving form data

Tags: pdf, forms

Is there a way with latex to enable Adobe Reader Extended PDF Features? I am creating a pdf form using hyperref/eforms and want users to be able to save the data entered into the form locally, and to be able to do so with older versions of Adobe reader.

I don't want to require users to email the form to me. I just want the data entered into the form to be able to be saved locally and retain all form editing capability.

Comment: Have you tried to google the question (le. g. "latex pdf form save" )? See here for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29842

Comment: I just tested the code (from Joseph Wright) here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842 and I can save the stuff with a current Adobe Reader (version DC). I think this is not a LaTeX question and rather a viewer related question.

Comment: I did read these threads already. Yes, it does seem that saving is enabled in adobe reader dc by default. So then it seems there isn't a latex package capable of enabling adobe's extended features? I'd like users with older versions of adobe reader to be able to save the form data as well.

Comment: Again, I think that it is independent of LaTeX packages. But maybe I am wrong. And it would be easier if you mention related questions so that others know what you know. It also shows research effort on your side.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly a viewer controlled capability to some extent. I was just wondering if there was a way to embed the relevant code in a pdf via tex/latex. I don't actually know what adobe extended pdf features are. I was just thinking there may have been some option in hyperref/eforms that I was overlooking. The comments here certainly help solve the mystery!

Comment: I go to bed now, actually watching Family Guy. Maybe others will have better answers tomorrow. I would recommend that you make your title clearer. At the moment it's not specific enough in my opinion.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate of the thread linked to because I am not only trying to enable saving data to a fillable form, but am specifically trying to enable all extended features. My subject war incomplete I suppose. But, I feel I have my answer, which is a negative, that what I am asking is not possible via latex.

Answer (score 4):

There are two applications which can apply Extended Rights to a PDF: Adobe Acrobat (Pro) and Adobe's Reader Extensions Server.

These Extended Rights allow Adobe (Acrobat) Reader to do things which are normally restricted.

However, with Adobe Reader XI, most of those restrictions (inflicted by Adobe) have been lifted. This means that these Extended Rights no longer need to be applied.

If old versions of Reader want to be supported (not the very best thing anyway, because Reader X and older are no longer supported by Adobe, so there are no security updates and bug fixes anymore), you would, as stated above, need Acrobat Pro to apply the rights needed according to he OP.

Comment: Yes this is basically the answer. There is no way to enable extended pdf features through latex. I was trying to avoid the acrobat solution. And there may be no lower cost software with the capability I seek. Maybe a trial version of acrobat would suffice as a one time fix. I will just have to require the end users to use the most up to date version of Adobe reader.

Comment: Using Acrobat as trial version for a one-time fix does do it. OTOH, getting users to the newest version of Acrobat Reader is not such a bad thing, because of security updates.