# Can TeX/LaTeX create fillable forms in a scanned pdf?

Tags: pdf, forms

I wonder if TeX/LaTeX can create fillable forms in a scanned pdf, such as [this one](https://docs.google.com/file/d/1tqjgoFeXuKOBvXDncBGa3ozY8Nbe_2AXZ5Go3SKatOP47iCyzhm-A5OTR9PP/edit?pli=1). I would like to fill out the places that are required to fill out. Thanks!

Comment: There's the [`eforms`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eforms) package (not in TeX Live unfortunately), for example.

Comment: See also [Creating fillable PDFs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14842/3954)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: (1) eforms is not in TeX Live, does it mean I will download it to somewhere that TeX can find? (2) The question you point to is for creating forms while creating the pdf, while my pdf is a scanned one already. So I wonder how that can be done?

Comment: (1) I wouldn't know; I've never installed this package manually. (2) Ah, I see. Then I am also not sure if `eforms` can be of help.

Comment: I'm confused.  You want TeX to create a .pdf with fillable forms in an *already* created .pdf?  Do you mean import the scanned .pdf into a new document and then somehow make it editable?  Whille I'd love to see someone's solution to that, wouldn't it be easier to make a new .pdf with fillable forms?  -- Note also that if you simply need to fill in the form, [pdfedit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/) on Linux will get the job done; I assume there are similar options for Windows, etc.

Comment: @jon: Thanks! I checked pdfedit, but didn't find it was able to fill text into a scanned pdf file as if filling a form .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is within TeX capabilities (using an existing form). You can do this using Adobe Acrobat Pro by going to Form -> Start Form Wizard. It will try to figure out the form fields automatically. The automatic detection is rarely correct, so I usually need to adjust some of the fields manually. There may be an open source way to do this, but I'm not aware of it.