# Is it possible to generate random numbers dynamically with javascript on a PDF?

Tags: pdf, random-numbers, javascript

PDFs can be used to manage javascript, such as the packages ocgtools, ocg-p, ocgx or ocgx2, which allow you to create interactive and clickable PDFs.
The hyperref package allows you to insert URLs or HTML anchors.

On the model of these packages, is it possible to create an interactive PDF file with a "go" button that when you click on it generates a random number (with javascript)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, e.g. with acrotex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
\begin{document}

\pushButton[\CA{Push me}\A{\JS{app.alert(Math.random())}}]{jsEx}{3cm}{12pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can sent values to other fields:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
\begin{document}

\textField{myField}{5cm}{12pt}

\pushButton[\CA{Push me}\A{\JS{this.getField("myField").value=Math.random();}}]{myButton}{3cm}{12pt}\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that these random numbers are not written in a javascript window but dynamically on the PDF itself?

Comment: You can sent them to textfields. I added an example

Comment: Sadly, not in TeX Live `:(`

Comment: @Fran: Easy to install. See the comment below this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385577/how-to-have-form-options-in-table-cells

Comment: @UlrikeFische Very interesting. Is it possible to fill this textfield with a random numerical expression like -3+2= where the + - signs and 2;3 numbers are randomly generated?

Comment: Sure, write a javascript function that generates your string and then use it -- but if it gets longer you should put it in an external file, see eformman.pdf.