# LaTeX PDF form: Detect CheckBox changed event

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, forms, javascript

I use LaTeX to create a fillable PDF document. How can I detect that a `\CheckBox` has been clicked?

It seems to react only to `onfocus={...}`, not to `onclicked={...}` or `onchanged{...}`.

Do I need to register an `EventListener` in an `insDLJS` environment?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
  \CheckBox[name=mytestbox,onchange={app.alert('Hello');},onclick={app.alert('Hello2');}]{Test CheckBox}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The event you are looking for is called `validate`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
  \CheckBox[name=mytestbox,validate={app.alert('Hello');}]{Test CheckBox}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

According to the hyperref documentation `validate` contains "JavaScript code to validate the entry", so using it as a general "changed" event might look like a hack, but in reality it generates a `/V` entry in the form fields additional actions dictionary. While this entry *can* be used for validation, that's only one possible use. It is [specified for PDF 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) as a general "onchange" event:

> (Optional; PDF 1.3) A JavaScript action that shall be performed when the field’s
>   value is changed. This action may check the new value for validity. (The name
>   V stands for “validate.”)

The advantage of using `validate` instead of e.g. `onmousedown` is that `validate` still works if a user uses another input method, for example selecting the field using the keyboard instead of clicking it with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

The events have other names, in hpdftex.def I find
onfocus, onblur, onmousedown, onmouseup, onenter, onexit. There is also onclick, but it seems to be implemented only for Pushbuttons.

Not every event makes really sense for check boxes, e.g. the mouse event seem to conflict with the checking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\CheckBox[name=mytestbox,onenter={app.alert('Hello');}]{Test CheckBox}

\CheckBox[name=mytestboxb,onexit={app.alert('Hello2');}]{Test CheckBox}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

An alternative to hyperref is eforms (acrotex), which has more options (and also more documentation). See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390882/2388

Comment: Thanks for your response. onenter and onexit are already triggered when the cursor hovers over the element (respectively leaves it). Onfocus would be more handy in that situation. 

I took a look into the eform documentation. There doesn't seem to be an onclick for the \CheckBox element either. Did I overlook something?

Comment: By the way, onmousedown and onmouseup don't work, unfortunately. I'll probably have to solve this with onfocus and onblur, which is only partially satisfying. I'm still wondering if an EventListener code be added manully...

Comment: `\checkBox[\AA{\AAMouseDown{\JS{app.alert("Mouse Down!")}}}]{myCheck}{10bp}{10bp}{On}` works fine for me with eforms.