# How to Control Multiple Save of a Single Form created using LaTeX?

Tags: pdf, forms

When I save this form, for every save I give, it produces new file (i.e, asking to save it new .pdfs), is there anyway that we can update all the saves in the single pdfs.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{rm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{center}
%\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{VITLogoNew}\\ [8pt]
\textbf{School of Mechanical and Building Sciences} \\ [4pt]
\textbf{M.Tech, Structural Engineering} \\ [4pt]
\textbf{Fall 2017 -- RBL - I Review}
\end{center}
\vskip 0.5cm 
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Name of the Reviewer:-} 
\ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.5cm,width=10.5cm,format = {textFont = 'Times New Roman'},combo,default=,name=Name of the Reviewer]{}{Faculty 1,  Faculty 2, Faculty 3} \\ [8pt]
\textbf{Date of Review:-} $\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_$ \\ [8pt]
\end{flushleft}
\begin{center}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}{
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.0cm}|p{4.8cm}|p{7.3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|} \cline{4-7}
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Group \#1}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Group \#2}} \\ \cline{4-7}
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \textbf{Student 1} & \textbf{Student 2} & \textbf{Student 1} & \textbf{Student 2} \\ \hline  
\textbf{S.No.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Criteria}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Sub-Criteria}} & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=2.4cm,combo,default=,name=group1name1]{}{17MST1001  , 17MST1002 , 17MST1003 , 17MST1004 , 17MST1005 , 17MST1006 , 17MST1008,    17MST1009,  17MST1010,  17MST1011,  17MST1012,  17MST1013,  17MST1014,  17MST1015,  17MST1017,  17MST1018,  17MST1019,  17MST1020,  17MST1021,  17MST1022,  17MST1023,  17MST1024,  17MST1025,  17MST1026,  17MST1027,  17MST1028,  17MST1029,  17MST1030,  17MST1031,  17MST1032,  17MST1033,  17MST1034,  17MST1035,  17MST1036,  17MST1037,  17MST1038,  17MST1039,  17MST1040,  17MST1041,  17MST1042,  17MST1043,  17MST1044,  17MST1045,  17MST1046,  17MST1047,  17MST1048,  17MST1049,  17MST1050,  17MST1051,  17MST1052,  17MST1053,  17MST1054} & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=2.4cm,combo,default=,name=group1name2]{}{17MST1001    , 17MST1002 , 17MST1003 , 17MST1004 , 17MST1005 , 17MST1006 , 17MST1008,    17MST1009,  17MST1010,  17MST1011,  17MST1012,  17MST1013,  17MST1014,  17MST1015,  17MST1017,  17MST1018,  17MST1019,  17MST1020,  17MST1021,  17MST1022,  17MST1023,  17MST1024,  17MST1025,  17MST1026,  17MST1027,  17MST1028,  17MST1029,  17MST1030,  17MST1031,  17MST1032,  17MST1033,  17MST1034,  17MST1035,  17MST1036,  17MST1037,  17MST1038,  17MST1039,  17MST1040,  17MST1041,  17MST1042,  17MST1043,  17MST1044,  17MST1045,  17MST1046,  17MST1047,  17MST1048,  17MST1049,  17MST1050,  17MST1051,  17MST1052,  17MST1053,  17MST1054} & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=2.4cm,combo,default=,name=group2name1]{}{17MST1001    , 17MST1002 , 17MST1003 , 17MST1004 , 17MST1005 , 17MST1006 , 17MST1008,    17MST1009,  17MST1010,  17MST1011,  17MST1012,  17MST1013,  17MST1014,  17MST1015,  17MST1017,  17MST1018,  17MST1019,  17MST1020,  17MST1021,  17MST1022,  17MST1023,  17MST1024,  17MST1025,  17MST1026,  17MST1027,  17MST1028,  17MST1029,  17MST1030,  17MST1031,  17MST1032,  17MST1033,  17MST1034,  17MST1035,  17MST1036,  17MST1037,  17MST1038,  17MST1039,  17MST1040,  17MST1041,  17MST1042,  17MST1043,  17MST1044,  17MST1045,  17MST1046,  17MST1047,  17MST1048,  17MST1049,  17MST1050,  17MST1051,  17MST1052,  17MST1053,  17MST1054} & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=2.4cm,combo,default=,name=group2name2]{}{17MST1001    , 17MST1002 , 17MST1003 , 17MST1004 , 17MST1005 , 17MST1006 , 17MST1008,    17MST1009,  17MST1010,  17MST1011,  17MST1012,  17MST1013,  17MST1014,  17MST1015,  17MST1017,  17MST1018,  17MST1019,  17MST1020,  17MST1021,  17MST1022,  17MST1023,  17MST1024,  17MST1025,  17MST1026,  17MST1027,  17MST1028,  17MST1029,  17MST1030,  17MST1031,  17MST1032,  17MST1033,  17MST1034,  17MST1035,  17MST1036,  17MST1037,  17MST1038,  17MST1039,  17MST1040,  17MST1041,  17MST1042,  17MST1043,  17MST1044,  17MST1045,  17MST1046,  17MST1047,  17MST1048,  17MST1049,  17MST1050,  17MST1051,  17MST1052,  17MST1053,  17MST1054} \\ \hline  
1. & \multirow{2}{*}{Presentation (30\%)} & Oral Presentation Skill (15\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box1]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7}
2. &  & Visual Aid used (15\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box2]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \hline 
3. & \multirow{2}{*}{Work  Accomplished (40\%)} & Quality of Work Done (20\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box3]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7}
4. &  & Completion of Work (20\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box4]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \hline 
5. & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Asnwering the Queries (10\%)} & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box5]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \hline 
6. & \multirow{2}{*}{Documentation (20\%)} & Content of the Report (10\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box6]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7}
7. &  & Report Preparation (Formatting) (10\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box7]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \hline 
& \multicolumn{2}{r|}{\textbf{Grand Total} (Out of 70)} & & & & \\ \hline
& \multicolumn{2}{r|}{\textbf{Percentage}} & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\begin{flushright}
\vskip 1.5cm 
\textbf{Signature of the Reviewer}
\end{flushright}
\end{center}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you compile your document? If you have saved the LaTeX code in a file `myfile.tex` and compile it from the command line with `pdflatex myfile`, it will overwrite the same pdf file every time. I suspect what you are doing is to use the preview facility of some editor.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer I intent to know the saving characteristics of output PDF file used for grading by the reviewer. Every marks allocated by the reviewer, when saved it ask for saving in a new file.

Comment: I have not used this, but it seems you can make the form mail the data to you or submit them to a server, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs. You would then have to create some sort of script that receives the data and appends them to a single large file or aggregates them by student and/or reviewer. That task is unrelated to LaTeX though.