# To-do documentclass for a document that is just a to-do list?

Tags: lists

Is there some LaTeX documentclass, or package, for creating a document that is *only* a to-do list, including check-boxes where one can mark those items done?

I am *not* asking about how to include a "to-do list" that consists of what are in effect annotations regarding what things still need to be done to complete the document itself.

For example, I might have a document like the following:

```
     1. Buy groceries.

        [X] (a) Lettuce

            (b) Oranges

            (c) Brie

[X]  2. Fill gas tank.

     3. Pick up kids from soccer.
```

(The preceding is *not* intended to be LaTeX markup code, but rather the sort of output desired.

I realize that one could just use standard `enumerate` environments, but as that stands it would miss inclusion of check-boxes to mark items that have been done. And something like the `todoenv` of the `todo` package does not seem to quite accomplish what I want, as that environment still produces a list separate from the main body of the document.

Is there such a suitable documentclass or package? Or must I "roll my own"?

Comment: Should the checkboxes be clickable in the PDF or just some boxes where one could place a tick by hand?

Comment: @Skillmon: preferably the checkboxes should be clickable in the PDF. (I could add those manually to the PDF using Adobe Acrobat, but that's tedious.)

Comment: possibly solved by hyperref clickable pdf check box see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs

Comment: As for a document class, you might try the [varwidth] option of standalone (assuming you don't need to print it).

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I *will* need to print the to-do list document. And I need the option of either marking an item as done by checking the box on the pdf or marking the LaTeX source that an item is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most basic from CTAN

It could be extensively modified to suit paper size etc is available as `{typed-checklist}`

Too many styles and options to show here but a simple case to match your mwe is

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt, convert={size=640x}]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article} %full page
\usepackage{typed-checklist} 

\begin{document}

\begin{CheckList}{Goal}

\Goal{open}{1. Buy groceries.}
  \begin{CheckList}{Task}
     \Task{done}{(a) Lettuce}
     \Task{started}{(b) Oranges}
     \Task{open}{(c) Brie}
  \end{CheckList}

 \Goal{achieved}{2. Fill gas tank.}

 \Goal{open}{3. Pick up kids from soccer.}

\end{CheckList}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm seeking; thanks! I am surprised that the package is designed in a way that the user does not Looks like this will meet my needs; thanks!  I am a bit surprised that `typed-checklist` automatically creates the lists without the user specifying `enumerate` or `itemize`; and that it requires the user to manually enter the counters. The latter means that rearranging items forces the user to manually renumber.  And hence no control over counter format by means of `enumitem`, say. Perhaps this is a necessary result of the package design, whose code I have not examined yet.

Comment: Yes I was supprised at having to add my own "numbered" entries I did not look closer at docs than to mock up your request so possibly did not use something more intuitive