# how to generate an editable pdf in latex?

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages, editors

I have a pdf file generated from latex document in overleaf. Now I want the complete document to be editable so that someone can directly edit the pdf without the latex file. Is it possible to do it using overleaf or is there any other way out for it? Please help.

Comment: PDF as a format is designed to make editing hard. some pdf editors can make limited changes, you don't need anything else from latex. But if you want an editable format are you sure you want to generate PDF at all?

Comment: As David Carlisle pointed out: PDF as a format is designed to make **editing** hard.  But you can create **fillable** forms with LaTeX - [Creating fillable PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14842/118714). [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [eforms](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eforms) come to my mnd.

Comment: Another option could probably be: Use the package [attachfile2](https://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2) for including the .tex-source of your document into the pdf-file. Then people can extract the .tex-file from the pdf-file, edit and afterwards compile it with LaTeX. But this workflow is not without LaTeX. :-(

Comment: Open the pdf using ms word (2013 or later)