# Matching question

Tags: tables

Is there a standard package for generating a matching question such as:
Match the following states with its capitals:

```
Michigan              Raleigh

North Carolina        Lansing

Minnesota             St.Paul
```

Comment: Don't you think that the question is too generic?

Comment: [Like this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15480/how-to-write-a-multiple-choice-test-book-with-latex)?

Comment: I think the OP may mean to have two vertical columns of text with white space in between so that pupils can draw lines connecting the states to their capitals. In which case the answer would probably involve a properly formatted `tabular` (see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) for example).

Comment: @ashpool: it would really help if you provide at the very least a image or a link to an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this user-defined environment `matchtabular` might be what you are looking for:

[image: Example]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{matchleft}
\newcounter{matchright}

\newenvironment{matchtabular}{%
  \setcounter{matchleft}{0}%
  \setcounter{matchright}{0}%
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{%
    >{\leavevmode\hbox to 1.5em{\stepcounter{matchleft}\arabic{matchleft}.}}X%
    >{\leavevmode\hbox to 1.5em{\stepcounter{matchright}\alph{matchright})}}X%
    }%
}{\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{matchtabular}
France & Washington DC \\ 
The United States of America & Berlin \\ 
The Czech Republic & Paris \\ 
Germany & Prague \\ 
\end{matchtabular}

\end{document}
```