# LaTeX using the matching environment in the exam documentclass

Tags: exam

Could someone please share a working example of using the matching environment in a document class exam.  I am new to using the exam document class and am unable to find a way to set up the matching style.  I found exactly what I wanted in a document written in 2001, but cannot make it work in the new class.  Here is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
% other information
\begin{document}

%exam header information

\begin{matching}[title={Match the following terms}]
    \pair{Field 1}{answer for 1}
    \pair{Field 2}{answer for 2}
    \pair{Field 3}{answer for 3}
\end{matching}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Take a look at this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197611/a-new-figure-environment-for-the-exam-class) Maybe can be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way I did it. I just used the tabular environment within the questions environment. The points can be counted with the question, but I do not have the solution print for this question. The macro `\midmatch` just puts in a line before each entry in the right column for the student to write the answer.

```
\newcommand{\midmatch}{\hspace{0.75in}\underline{\hspace{0.5in}     }}
```

Then, after the `\begin{document}`, within the questions environment:

```
\fullwidth{\section{Matching}}
\question[5]
Match the property of matter from the left column with the appropriate measurement device or technique on the right.
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
a.  &   Temperature &   \midmatch   &   Thermometer\\
&&&\\
b.  &   Pressure    &   \midmatch   &   Graduated Cylinder\\
&&&\\
c.  &   Length      &   \midmatch   &   Spectrometer\\
&&&\\
d.  &   Volume      &   \midmatch   &   Ruler\\
&&&\\
e.  &   Color       &   \midmatch   &   Manometer
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62836/39194) may be helpful to you.  [Here's another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192204/39194) that may give you some ideas but it does not use the `exam` class.

Here's my custom matching environment, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13106/39194).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

%\printanswers

\usepackage{multicol}

%% Create a Matching question format
\newcommand*\Matching[1]{
\ifprintanswers
    \textbf{#1}
\else
    \rule{2.1in}{0.5pt}
\fi
}
\newlength\matchlena
\newlength\matchlenb
\settowidth\matchlena{\rule{2.1in}{0pt}}
\newcommand\MatchQuestion[2]{%
    \setlength\matchlenb{\linewidth}
    \addtolength\matchlenb{-\matchlena}
    \parbox[t]{\matchlena}{\Matching{#1}}\enspace\parbox[t]{\matchlenb}{#2}}


\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\fullwidth{Match the \emph{most appropriate} term to each concept.  Not all terms are used. No term is used twice. (2 points each)}
\vspace{-1\baselineskip}
\fullwidth{%
\begin{multicols}{3}
Match 1 \\
Match 2 \\
Match 3 \\
Match 4 \\
Match 5 \\
Match 6 
\end{multicols}

}
\vspace{0.7\baselineskip}

\question\MatchQuestion{Match 3}{Which answer qoes with this question?}
\vspace{0.7\baselineskip}

\question\MatchQuestion{Match 5}{Which answer qoes with this question?}
\vspace{0.7\baselineskip}

\question\MatchQuestion{Match 2}{Which answer qoes with this question?}
\vspace{0.7\baselineskip}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Blank lines are printed for the exams.

[image]

Answers are printed when `\printanswers` is uncommented.

[image]