# How to type multiple choice questions with more than one correct choice

Tags: book-design, exercises

I want to type multiple choice question (which may have two or more answer) book using exercise package such as

```
\begin{questions}
\question This is the first question
\choice Wrong answer
\correctchoice This is a correct answer
\correctchoice This is another answer
\choice Wrong answer

\question
....
\end{questions}
```

I want to type the answer at the end of the book with chapter name and exercise number or page number of the book. The choices in  the questions must be in a single row or in two rows to save the space.

In the answer sheet, I like to give explanation  to select the answer.

Comment: Do the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15480/how-to-write-a-multiple-choice-test-book-with-latex) help you?

Comment: Does it have to be the [`exercise`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exercise) package?

Comment: As two correct answers are in my question, answer must be as Qn.No. B &C .It is possible to add comments in answer to explain why i choose the answer by using exercise package

Comment: @S.G.Sekaran you can always edit your question to add more details. I was asking because I have an idea how to do this with another package.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is a bit confusing: you refer to the [`exercise`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exercise) package but are using commands in your code snippets that are defined by the [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) class... Then you're talking about a book with a separate answers section but also say

> In the answer sheet, I like to [...]

Since I now don't know what package/class you want to use and you never really answered my comment if you're bound to a specific package, and since it is also not really clear if you want to design a book or a exercise sheet/answer sheet combination (or maybe both?) I'll give a solution for the `exam` class creating sheets and one for the [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) package for use in a textbook.

### Using the `exam` class

The `exam` class obviously is not meant to create a textbook. But exercise/answer sheets can be created with it. Remove or add the class option `answers` to see the difference:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
 \question This is the first question.
 \ifprintanswers\emph{Info:} Correct choices are marked bold.\fi
 \begin{checkboxes}
  \choice Wrong answer
  \correctchoice This is a correct answer
  \correctchoice This is another answer
  \choice Wrong answer
 \end{checkboxes}
 \question This is the second question.
 \ifprintanswers\emph{Info:} Correct choices are marked bold.\fi
 
 \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
  \correctchoice True
  \choice False
  \correctchoice True
  \choice false
 \end{oneparcheckboxes}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Using the `exsheets` package

The `exsheets` package can be used to create exams, exercise/answer sheets or exercises in textbooks. The following example will show how to add exercises and solutions and print the solutions in a separate section or chapter.

#### Using `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=se.qu}

% due to a bug in versions >0.3a:
\providecommand*\checkedchoicebox{\ckeckedchoicebox}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{itemize}{1}
\newlist{choices*}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist[choices*]{itemjoin=\qquad}
\newcommand*\choice{\item[\choicebox]}
\newcommand*\correctchoice{\PrintSolutionsTF{\item[\checkedchoicebox]}{\item[\choicebox]}}

\begin{document}
\section{Exercises}
\begin{question}\label{qu:one}
 This is the first question.
 \begin{choices}
  \choice Wrong answer
  \correctchoice This is a correct answer
  \correctchoice This is another answer
  \choice Wrong answer
 \end{choices}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
 This is the first question.
 \begin{choices}
  \choice Wrong answer
  \correctchoice This is a correct answer
  \correctchoice This is another answer
  \choice Wrong answer
 \end{choices}
 You find the question on page~\pageref{qu:one}.
\end{solution}
\begin{question}\label{qu:two}
 This is the second question.
 
 \begin{choices*}
  \correctchoice True
  \choice False
  \correctchoice True
  \choice false
 \end{choices*}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
 This is the second question.
 
 \begin{choices*}
  \correctchoice True
  \choice False
  \correctchoice True
  \choice false
 \end{choices*}
 
 \noindent You find the question on page~\pageref{qu:two}.
\end{solution}

\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### With >v0.3a of `exsheets`

The next update of `exsheets` will not only fix a few issues such as the `\ckeckedchoicebox` but also provide a possibility without `enumitem`. A working version can be [downloaded here](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/overview), the update to CTAN will have to wait a few days, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=se.qu}

\NewTasks[style=multiplechoice]{choices}[\choice]
\newcommand*\correct{\checkedchoicebox}

\begin{document}
\section{Exercises}
\begin{question}\label{qu:one}
 This is the first question.
 \begin{choices}
  \choice Wrong answer
  \choice This is a correct answer
  \choice This is another answer
  \choice Wrong answer
 \end{choices}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
 This is the first question.
 \begin{choices}
  \choice Wrong answer
  \choice[\correct] This is a correct answer
  \choice[\correct] This is another answer
  \choice Wrong answer
 \end{choices}
 You find the question on page~\pageref{qu:one}.
\end{solution}
\begin{question}\label{qu:two}
 This is the second question.
 \begin{choices}{4}
  \choice True
  \choice False
  \choice True
  \choice false
 \end{choices}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
 This is the second question.
 \begin{choices}{4}
  \choice[\correct] True
  \choice False
  \choice[\correct] True
  \choice false
 \end{choices}
 \noindent You find the question on page~\pageref{qu:two}.
\end{solution}

\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Comment: TeX Live does not have `exsheets` package.

Comment: You mean TL 2012? Mine has it (v0.3 since today)...

Comment: TL 2012 has no the package.

Comment: [Yes, it does](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets)! Maybe the mirror you're updating from does not have it, though...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a new user in Latex. Kindly explain  the method of installing exsheets and enumitem packages.

Comment: @S.G.Sekaran Have a look at [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5049) or maybe [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/5049) or [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/5049).

Comment: I am using window 7 and MiKTex2.9.  I am not able to install exsheets package. I didn't see localtexmf or texmf in C:.  I tried to use as: C:programfiles/miktex2.9/tex/latex/exsheets. But, when i run the programme, I see that exsheets.sty not found. Kindly help me to install it.

Comment: @S.G.Sekaran Why don't you just use the [MiKTeX package manager](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55473#55473)

Comment: @cgnieder I have seen your answer. It is nice. My idea is as follows: For a Qn. No.2, in the multiple choice question, suppose  A & C options are correct. The answer must be printed as 2 - A & C.

Comment: @S.G.Sekaran I don't understand your comment. You can use anything you like inside the `{solution}` environment

Comment: (except verbatim material that is)

Comment: with the switch to `tasks.sty` (I guess), the third solution does no longer work. One has to load the package with `\usepackage[load-tasks]{exsheets}` then this works fine again AFAICT @cgnieder btw please reconsider your MC-hatred ;)

Comment: @stefanct who or what is MC and why do you think I hate it? As for the other comment: this answer is rather old and there've been many changes to `exsheets` in the meantime...

Comment: MC stands for multiple choice ;) yes, the answer is dated, however, it is still valid and has helped me (apart from the tiny option problem).