# Error in installing packages

Tags: errors, packages, installing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix the error “GUI framework cannot be initialized” with TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27138/how-can-i-fix-the-error-gui-framework-cannot-be-initialized-with-texniccenter)

I am using window7 and MiKTeX2.9. I want to install new packages which is not seen in miktex package manager. I put the *.sty in C:programefiles/miktex2.9/tex/latex/*. When I run a programme, I see that GUI framework cannot be initialized. No error and no output. Let me the error I have committed.

Comment: If the package is a standard one, MikTeX should install it inself and you don't need to put any files anywhere. If it's not a standard one, try to use these instructions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2066/11002

Comment: read the accepted answer of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27138/how-can-i-fix-the-error-gui-framework-cannot-be-initialized-with-texniccenter

Comment: I believe this question is referring to [a comment to an aswer of mine using the `exsheets` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76416/how-to-type-multiple-choice-questions-with-more-than-one-correct-choice/79197#comment175771_79197). This suggests that the standard way should work as [`exsheets` is part of MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/packages/exsheets).