# Printing solution of mcq using xsim

Tags: xsim

How to print the solution of multiple choice question in the following example ?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[clear-aux]{xsim}

\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb,fmtcount}
\newlist{choices}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[choices]{label=$\Box$}
\newcommand*\choice{\item}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{choices}
\DeclareExerciseProperty*{multiple}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{mc}
  {%
    \UseExerciseTemplate{begin}{default}%
    \IfExerciseBooleanPropertyTF{multiple}
      {Select one or more correct answers}
      {%
        \GetExercisePropertyT{choices}
          {Select \numberstringnum{#1} correct answer\ifnum#1>1 s\fi.}%
      }%
    \begin{choices}
  }
  {%
    \end{choices}
    \UseExerciseTemplate{end}{default}%
  }

\DeclareExerciseType{mc}{
  exercise-env = multiplechoice ,
  solution-env = correctchoices ,
  exercise-name = Question ,
  solution-name = Solution ,
  exercise-template = mc ,
  solution-template = mc ,
  counter = exercise
}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name = Question ,
  solution/name = Solution
}

\begin{document}

\section{Questions}
\begin{multiplechoice}[choices=1]
  \choice one
  \choice two
  \choice three
  \choice four
\end{multiplechoice}

\begin{exercise}
  Answer this question on a separate sheet.  
\end{exercise}

\begin{multiplechoice}[multiple]
  \choice one
  \choice two
  \choice three
  \choice four
\end{multiplechoice}

\begin{multiplechoice}[choices=2]
  \choice one
  \choice two
  \choice three
  \choice four
\end{multiplechoice}

\end{document}
```

I tried with

```
%preamble
exercise/print = true,
solution/print = true,

%document
\begin{correctchoices}
    \choice two
\end{correctchoices}
```

But it is giving odd output.

Also, is it possible to mark the answer on the question itself while printing solution?

Comment: As I wrote in my previous answer: Use the correct key (`correctchoices/print=true` in this case).

Comment: even if I give 'correctchoices/print=false', it is still printing the solution. Also the solution is getting printed alongwith the line "Select one or more correct answers" which I don't need. The answer also includes a box.

Comment: Also, is it possible to mark the answer on the question itself while printing solution?

Comment: I am looking for something like this (done with exam class) in the following link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76416/how-to-type-multiple-choice-questions-with-more-than-one-correct-choice ... However in this case, with xsim.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with version 0.17 (2020/02/21) `xsim` has the exercise property `solution` which tells `xsim` to use the same environment body for the exercise and the solution. This is very convenient here. Using `\IfInsideSolutionTF` then allows us to insert the checkmark where needed:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xsim}[2020/02/21]

\usepackage{enumitem,fontawesome,fmtcount,multicol}
\newlist{choices}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[choices]{label=\faSquareO}

\newcommand*\correct{\IfInsideSolutionTF{\faCheckSquareO}{\faSquareO}}

\newcommand*\choice{\item}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{choices}
\DeclareExerciseProperty*{multiple}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{mc}
  {%
    \UseExerciseTemplate{begin}{default}%
    \IfExerciseBooleanPropertyTF{multiple}
      {Select one or more correct answers}
      {%
        \GetExercisePropertyT{choices}
          {Select \numberstringnum{#1} correct answer\ifnum#1>1 s\fi.}%
      }%
    \begin{choices}
  }
  {%
    \end{choices}
    \UseExerciseTemplate{end}{default}%
  }

\DeclareExerciseType{mc}{
  exercise-env = multiplechoice ,
  solution-env = correctchoices ,
  exercise-name = Question ,
  solution-name = Solution ,
  exercise-template = mc ,
  solution-template = mc ,
  counter = exercise
}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name = Question ,
  solution/name = Solution ,
  print-solutions/headings=false
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Questions}
\begin{multiplechoice}[choices=1,solution]
  \choice one
  \choice[\correct] two
  \choice three
  \choice four
\end{multiplechoice}

\begin{exercise}
  Answer this question on a separate sheet.  
\end{exercise}

\begin{multiplechoice}[multiple,solution]
  \choice[\correct] one
  \choice two
  \choice three
  \choice[\correct] four
\end{multiplechoice}

\begin{multiplechoice}[choices=2,solution]
  \choice one
  \choice[\correct] two
  \choice three
  \choice[\correct] four
\end{multiplechoice}

\columnbreak

\section{Answers}
\printsolutions
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]