# Package for Creating Forms?

Tags: packages, forms

I'm looking for a dedicated package that supports typesetting forms. In my imagination it provides different form fields (similar to UI kits) that can be composed in a simple grid. I understand that `hyperref` can be used to [create PDF forms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14845/3083) but it provides mostly the mechanics and not components. I'm looking for pointers and examples for forms created with LaTeX. Maybe we can turn this into a community wiki.

Aside: Form design is part craft and part art and I would be happy to see more support for forms given that tables are already well supported in LaTeX. A wonderful book about form design (in German) is [Formulare gestalten](http://www.amazon.de/Formulare-gestalten-Handbuch-Gestalter-Gestaltungsfragen/dp/3874397084/) by Borries Schwesinger. Below is a spread from that book with examples for well-designed forms.

[image]

Comment: Without a deep understanding of PDF (well Adobe JavaScript actually) it's not easy (I lack it competely) and I believe it's no wonder why we do not have a package yet -- but I request it as well

Comment: I think a package for paper forms would be exciting already even when forms would not turn into fillable PDF forms.

Comment: Oh, paper 'only'... let's develop one!

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9975/package-to-create-a-printable-form especially http://www.qdds.org/fileadmin/files/Documentation_en_papi.pdf

Comment: @ChristianLindig: In the end -- it's most likely a tabular background and some macros for the individual parts

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I can also imagine boxes of a defined size that assemble well without a table. Say, if each box is a multiple of 1/12th of the available page width and box height is a multiple of line hight, this could also work.

Comment: For an irregular page layout I line to use tikzpagenodes.  Format each form using LaTeX and pop in into a node.